YAML pipeline builds and deploys successfully, but the wrong files appear in the wwwroot of the SCM site
I'm new to using YAML pipelines and I think i've configured something incorrectly. YAML script at the end.
In the deployment center, I connected it to my dev branch:

When I check the SCM wwwroot (https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/), the files seem like they're from another branch. They don't have some files that are only in dev.
And when I check the app settings url, https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings, the json shows a master branch, which I don't even have. If I update that variable in env variables, it'll show dev. But it doesn't seem like it makes a difference to the deployment.

trigger:
- dev

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        version: '8.x'
        includePreviewVersions: true

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Restore project dependencies'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build the project'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Publish the project'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        publishWebProjects: true
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish artifacts'
      inputs:
        pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
        artifactName: 'drop'

- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    environment: 'production'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '<subscription>'
              appName: '<appName>'
              appType: 'webApp'
              package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'


The problem was the deployment slot. Even though I had set it up through the deployment center, my app service didn't actually have any deployment slots. I removed the deployment center connection and it worked correctly.
